# What is the maximum number of counters of each colour ever needed for this game?

Tags: polynomials

I have a 10x10 square baseboard, plus 2 six sided dice, and 5 different coloured bags of plastic counters.

Objective : fill as much of the baseboard as possible with randomly generated arrays, ensuring adjacent arrays have different coloured counters.

Method: Roll the 2 die to create an array in the range 1x2 to 6x6. Find enough squares on the baseboard to fill with counters.

Repeat roll of die and fill with counters, using a different colour for differentiation where part or all of an array is adjacent to another array.

Continue until all possible spaces for arrays are covered. I.e no spaces or only single spaces are unfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I think a greedy approach works here: allocating maximal size rectangles of one color with as few as possible borders between them:

```
111111.222
111111.222
111111.222
111111.222
111111.222
111111.222
..........
333333.444
333333.444
333333.444
```

Steps

1. 6x6 rectangle, placed in the corner, it occupies 7x7 fields considering the border. If you move it in any direction, it will occupy more fields with no increased usage of the given color (7x8, 8x7 or even 8x8 fields are consumed for placing the same 6x6 pieces) because the new border(s) appearing, greed works so far
2. in the remaining fields, 6x3 or 3x6 is the maximal rectangle you can put, occupying 7x3 (or 3x7) new fields (and re-using the existing borders), moving them around makes things worse again, so they have to go into a corner (and does not matter which)
3. is the pair for 2, occupying 3x7 fields
4. just fills up what remains, introducing no new borders

Then 6*6+3*6+6*3+3*3=81 pieces of a single color which you may ever need.

Some numbers/expressions may be used to justify why one should be greedy, I would attempt comparing $\frac{color\ coverage}{total\ coverage}$ ratios. The best would be 1, covering the entire field with one color, just it is not allowed by the maximal rectangle size, so then comes the 6x6 rectangle, if it is placed in a corner, the ratio is $\frac{6*6}{7*7}$, an "edge" rectangle has something lower $\frac{6*6}{8*7}$, and if it goes floating around, ratio goes down to $\frac{6*6}{8*8}$. Reducing the size does not help either, $\frac{6*5}{7*6}$ is also less (than $\frac{6*6}{7*7}$).

Related expressions would be
$$\frac{n*k}{(n+1)*(k+1)}>\frac{n*k}{(n+1)*(k+2)}$$
and
$$\frac{n*k}{(n+1)*(k+1)}>\frac{n*(k-1)}{(n+1)*k}$$
Both for $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

In fact I am stuck here, because this is still just step 1 and I have no idea how to say anything about maximizing the sum of rectangle sizes.

Side note: I am not sure why your minimal rectangle would be 1x2 instead of 1x1.